# How to find average time taken for state transition using eloquent or DB query

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a table(state_histories) like this.

| entity_type | entity_id | status | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| invoice | 1 | New | 2020-04-16 06:24:50 |
| invoice | 1 | Claim | 2020-04-16 07:24:50 |
| invoice | 2 | New | 2020-04-16 07:34:50 |
| invoice | 2 | Hold | 2020-04-16 07:44:50 |
| invoice | 1 | Paid | 2020-04-16 08:24:50 |
| invoice | 2 | Claim | 2020-04-16 09:34:50 |

I want to find the average time taken transit invoice from NEW status to CLAIM status using Eloquent or DB query.

For the above output should be 90 mins.

Comment: Why 120 mins? Invoice Id 1 took 60 mins, invoice id 2 took 120. Shouldn't be 90 mins the expected value?

Comment: Yeah sorry fixed it.

Comment: If there's can only be a single 'new' and ''claim' entry, maybe try something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=929d9158947531d0cb75d4dd3f07d9ca

Answer (score 0):

Before getting into the answer it's better to think of another way than creating a new row for a new status for an invoice maybe add some columns to refer time for status changed to claim with that being said
you can get the created_at and assign to either with Dayname or Carbon
in Carbon after assign it using createFromFormat so you do it for new and claim
and then there is a method called diffInSeconds you can call for a minute to get the difference for one entity. do it for all of the entities and in the end get the addition of them on the number of different entitie